# How to sort randomly with Doctrine DBAL, TYPO3 and TypoScript

Tags: doctrine-orm, typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-9.x, dbal

Creating a query by `TypoScript` in TYPO3 v8 the Doctrine-Framework is already used to create the SQL-query. The following code throws an error but was possible in former TYPO3 versions:

```
lib.myElement = CONTENT
lib.myElement {
  wrap =  <div class="inner-wrapper">|</div>
  required = 1

  table = tt_content
  select.languageField = sys_language_uid
  select.pidInList = {$pidConstant}
  select.max = 1
  select.where = colPos = 0
  select.orderBy = RAND()
  select.selectFields = bodytext,image,header,header_link
  renderObj=COA
  renderObj{
      ...
  }
}
```

In TYPO3 version 8 now is an error logged with this essence:

```
{"exception":"Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\Mysqli\\MysqliException: Unknown column 'rand()' in 'order clause'...}
```

So is it still possible to sort randomly and if yes, what's the trick to get it running on base of the TypoScript above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to add RAND() to the fieldlist and assign an alias. The alias can be used for sorting.

```
lib.myElement = CONTENT
lib.myElement {
  wrap =  <div class="inner-wrapper">|</div>
  required = 1

  table = tt_content
  select.languageField = sys_language_uid
  select.pidInList = {$pidConstant}
  select.max = 1
  select.where = colPos = 0
  select.orderBy = my_alias
  select.selectFields = bodytext,image,header,header_link,RAND() as my_alias
  renderObj=COA
  renderObj{
      ...
  }
}
```